# Using django query language to query connected objects

Tags: django, django-orm

I just started working with the django query language, and am having some difficulties. I want the method **get_present_users()** to return all the users that are connected to a certain Drink object, with a "Presence" object. I know I can get all relevant presence objects with:

```
Presence.objects.filter(event=self.pk)
```

However, I can't think of a way of turning this queryset to all the users. Could you guys help me a hand?

```
class Drink(BaseModel):
    date = models.DateField()
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Presence(BaseModel):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Drink)
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='presence_submitted_by')
    present_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='presence_present_user')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to write a function that gets all of the `Users` that can be associated with a `Drink` by a `Presence` object [you can make use of the reverse relationship of a User to a Presence.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) Instead of trying to go from a `Presence` and get a list of `Users`.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

...

class Drink(model.Models):
    ...

    def get_present_users(self):
        return User.objects.filter(presence_present_user__event=self)

...
```

Which will allow you to write:

```
drink = Drink.objects.get(id=1)
print(drink.get_present_users())
>> [<User: >, <User: >]
```